# FileIO.WriteTextAsync(IStorageFile, String) error: Windows is not defined

Tags: javascript, file-io, winjs

My code:

```
var x = [{" Id ": " 1 ", " UserName ": " Sam Smith "},
         {" Id ": " 2 ", " UserName ": " Fred Frankly "}]
Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync("par2.txt", x)
```

Is producing the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Windows is not defined
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide the exact call you used and the exact error message you got?

Comment: var x = [{" Id ": " 1 ", " UserName ": " Sam Smith "}, {" Id ": " 2 ", " UserName ": " Fred Frankly "}]
Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync("par2.txt", x)

Error im getting is: Uncaught ReferenceError: Windows is not defined

Comment: Am I missing something or are you trying to use a C# method in a JavaScript system?

Comment: if (file !== null) {
    Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, "Swift as a shadow").done(function () {
        // Perform additional tasks after file is written
    },
    // Handle errors with an error function
    function (error) {
        // Handle errors encountered during write
    });
}I am trying to use this like this and this is to be written in javascript

Comment: Ok. In order to use the Windows API, you have to include the correct libraries. Are you using Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: I have Microsoft Visual Studio.But how to use it in javascript?